# Javascript - generate new random number without displaying old one

Tags: javascript

I press the "Generate" button and it it generates a password, that's great but everytime I press the "Generate" button afterwards it only adds to the first password. How can I just generate a new password without the old one being displayed?

I tried adding a plus sign and changing the the arrays to strings.

```
const characters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "~", "`", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "^", "&", "*", "(", ")", "_", "-", "+", "=", "{", "[", "}", "]", ",", "|", ":", ";", "<", ">", ".", "?",
    "/"
];
let passwordOne = "";
let passwordTwo = "";


let generateBtn = document.getElementById("generate-btn");
let firstPasswordEl = document.getElementById("first-password-el");
let secondPasswordEl = document.getElementById("second-password-el");

function generate() {
    randomOne()
    firstPasswordEl.textContent += passwordOne
    randomTwo()
    secondPasswordEl.textContent += passwordTwo
};

function randomOne() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        let character = Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length)
        passwordOne += characters[character]
    }
};

function randomTwo() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        let character = Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length)
        passwordTwo += characters[character]
    }
};
```

Comment: You are concatenating to the element. Do not do `+=` when writing it to the element. `firstPasswordEl.textContent = passwordOne`

Comment: [Maybe useful](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-7p9d8r?file=index.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently using the [addition assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Addition_assignment) to set the text content of your elements. This will add the right hand side to the current value. You could resolve this by swapping to the assignment operator, '='.

```
firstPasswordEl.textContent = passwordOne
```

Comment: And inside the randomOne and randomeTwo functions maybe reset the global variables of passwordOne and passwordTwo.